# WPF: Set a property value from another property value at design time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a custom control from a Label. I have added a new dependency property "MyCaption". I made the Content proeprty as hidden:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public new string Content { get; set; }
```

Now, I want this behaviour: if I set MyCaption value, I want Content is set with that value too, at design time.

Some ideas?

EDIT: I tried to define my dependency property like this, but it doesn't work:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCaptionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyCaption ",
                                typeof(string),
                                typeof(TMSLabel));

    [Description("Valore della label"), Category("MyProperties")] 
    public string MyCaption 
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyCaptionProperty); }
        set { 
            SetValue(MyCaptionProperty, value);
            Content = value;
        }
    }
```

HINT: If I remove the code that made che Content property as hidden, the code above works!

Comment: Isidor are you looking for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx ?

Comment: I don't need to have a different behaviour at desing or run time. At run time I can have that  easily with binding, but at design time I can't.

Comment: Is that your intention that your custom control trying to hide the Label content property ? 
What are you trying to do by hiding the original "Content" property  ?

public new string Content { get; set; }

Comment: My intent is hide the Content property in the Properties View.

Comment: Oops ... than my answer below probably won't help you. One thing to point out that your MyCaption property only works when you do that at code behind. The assignment won't work if you assign MyCaption value from xmal. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From - http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Important: Do not add any logic to these properties, because they are only called when you set the property from code. If you set the property from XAML the SetValue() method is called directly.

So, trying to set Content property from the Dependency Property setting doesn't sounds right.

How about try to use the PropertyChangedCallBack instead

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyCaption ",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(MyLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnChangedCallback));

    public string MyCaption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyCaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCaptionProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var labelControl = d as Label;
        if (labelControl != null)
            labelControl.Content = e.NewValue;
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfTestProj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:wpfTestProj="clr-namespace:WpfTestProj"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<wpfTestProj:MyLabel MyCaption="This is a test" />
```